# Racket Rainbow Shape Recursion

Tags: recursion, racket

I am trying to make a recursive function in Racket where from a list of colours, the function will print out multiple shapes in that order of colours. However, the function is not printing anything but "Empty List".

```
#lang slideshow
(require 2htdp/image)

(define a (list "red" "Orange" "Yellow" "Green" "Blue" "Purple"))

(define (Rainbow lst)
  (cond
   [(empty? lst) "Empty List"]
   [else (circle 20 "solid" (first lst))
         (Rainbow (rest lst))]))

(Rainbow a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The displaying in REPL is done when a function returns an image. Your call `(Rainbow a)` can be rewritten as sequence of `(begin (circle 20 "solid" ...) ...)` (`cond` has implicit begin, so in each recursive step, one `begin` is added), finished with `"Empty List"` and `begin` returns last expression, so `"Empty List"` is finally returned:

```
> (begin (circle 20 "solid" "Red")
         (begin (circle 20 "solid" "Orange")
                (begin (circle 20 "solid" "Yellow")
                       "Empty List")))

"Empty List"
```

But you can use `print` and print that image into REPL:

```
#lang slideshow
(require 2htdp/image)

(define a (list "Red" "Orange" "Yellow" "Green" "Blue" "Purple"))

(define (Rainbow lst)
  (cond
   [(empty? lst) (void)]
   [else (print (circle 20 "solid" (first lst)))  
         (Rainbow (rest lst))]))

(Rainbow a)
```

Note that I used [`void`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/void.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._void%29%29), so my REPL contains only colored circles and no other text.